# iOS: Change contentView backgroundColor on touchDown in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

**QUESTION**

I need to change the contentView's backgroundColor property on a touchDown event in a custom UITableViewCell.  I have added a UIButton to the cell, but cannot seem to figure out how to make it reload the cell and change the cell's contentView backgroundColor.

**What I've Tried:**

I add the target to the UIButton in cellForRow:atIndexPath: like this:

```
[cell.touchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButtonAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

This is my method that should reload the cell that was selected:

```
-(void) touchButtonAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cellSelected = YES;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

When that cell reloads, this is the code that should change the contentView's background color:

```
if (cellSelected) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

I'm receiving an error in my touchButtonAtIndexPath: method, this is the error:

```
-[UIButton section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Anyone know how I can update the custom UITableViewCell's contentView backgroundColor on touchDown?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: If you add an action to the button the receiving parameter will be the button that triggered the event, not an NSIndexPath.

2: The easiest solution would be just handle the button action inside the cell and change the background colour there

With these in mind your code could be something like this:

In your cell, when you set it up you add the action targeting to the cell itself. So in your custom tableview cell you add the target in your setup method, or you can do this even from stroyboard:

```
[self.touchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And in the same cell you handle the tap event, and change the background colour

```
-(void) buttonTouched:(UIButton)button {
   self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I needed, but I don't understand how the buttonTouched: method is connected to the cell.  When I use this code, I get a pretty obvious error: property 'contentView' not found on object of type...

Comment: you have to call the addTarget method inside the cell, and the buttonTouched method also has to  be implemented inside your custom tableview cell.

Comment: I have that already, I'm getting that error because I'm passing self.contentView and it should be something like cell.contentView.  Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: no, if the buttonTouched method is implemented INSIDE your custom tableview cell subclass, self.contentView should exist. If it doesn't exist, the method is not in your tableView cell subclass, or it is not a subclass of UITableView

Comment: ooooohhhhhh..... duh, of course!  Ok in the actual custom tableviewcell class I do this.  I was trying to do it in my UIViewController that had the tableview.  Awesome, this works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use these delegate functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // Do your stuff when selected
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  // Do your stuff when unselected

}
```

Comment: My cell is not responding to these methods, but this really isn't what I'm looking for.  I want to turn highlight off and make my own highlight.

Comment: These methods is built for highlight personnalization. I'm used to use them in my project